# model.set_weights(model.get_weights()) returning error

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I am working in a multithreaded environment and passing weights to a function and recreating a model there.  Now, in my function even `model.set_weights(model.get_weights())` is not working.

I've tried using `K.clear_session` and setting weights layer by layer, but neither work.

My code's intent was to be:

```py
def create_model(parameters=None):
    """Create a model from weights."""
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    import keras.backend as K
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    if parameters:
        model.set_weights(parameters)
    else:
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSProp', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

However even...

```py
def create_model(parameters=None):
    """Create a model from weights."""
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    import keras.backend as K
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    if parameters:
        model.set_weights(model.get_weights()) # <--------------
    else:
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSProp', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

...does not work.

I get the error `ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(8, 12) dtype=float32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("dense_1/kernel:0", shape=(8, 12), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)` when running my program.  Keep in mind that this takes place in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: ----------
Have you tried writing the save to a file then loading from that file?

Comment: No, I'll try that.

Comment: I can't even save the model.  It gives me the same error as before.